# Windows Install-package keeps installer files

Tags: windows-10, windows-packagemanagement

I am using Windows 10 OneGet package manager with several providers like chocolatey. I have several providers including chocolatey, and I install packages like this

```
Install-Package [pckg_name]
```

When the provider is chocolatey for example, the main installer for the program is downloaded in a temp chocolatey subdirectory and executed from here. Then the program installs itself in `C:\Program files\` and registers normally.

I have noticed that the installer files remain on the disk after installing (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey contains subdirectories `firefox/`, `git/`, etc.). This is probably going to add up to GBs after some time...

I am surprised the `Install-Package` cmd doesn't get rid of those files after successful installation. My main disk is a SSD and I don't have infinite storage space.

So my questions are

- Why are .exe, .msi installers not removed automatically after installation ?
- Is there a way to set such behavior ?
- Is there a command to clean these files across all providers ?

Comment: When an application is removed it actually runs the installer to remove the program.  I don't understand your other two questions.

Comment: `it actually runs the installer to remove the program` Are you sure ? I really don't think so. The applications are registered on windows programs list and there is usually an uninstaller program that is different and light (sometimes this uninstaller can also perform repairs or component modifications, but it is different from the installer grabbed from the internet).

Comment: Having made several installers in the past, and knowing how .msi files work, I am 100% positive of my statement.  While there is a ".unist" or whatever it is named, the .msi, is still required.

Comment: So you mean that when I download a random installer file from the internet in my `download` directory (that I usually clean quite often), that files gets copied again somewhere else so I can uninstall the software later ?? Whenever I install a software it actually requires close to 2x the actual program size as it needs to keep the installer (minus compression) ?